Filebeat: setting elasticsearch index name per input
I'm trying to setup filebeat so that I have two log sources that end up in different indexes of the target logstash. All involved services' (filebeat, logstash, elastic) versions are 8.12.0.
I've found this question on the elk forum with the solution "you can set the index per input" (as documented here).
However, setting up my input section like this doesn't seem to work; the data seems to get lost altogether. Here is my full filebeat config:
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: filestream
    id: "filestream-id"
    enabled: true
    index: "index-id"
    paths:
      - /usr/share/filebeat/logs/*.log

fields_under_root: true

processors:
  - dissect:
      tokenizer: "/usr/share/filebeat/logs/%{service_name}.log"
      field: "log.file.path"
      target_prefix: ""

output.logstash:
  hosts: [ "loghost:5044" ]

However, the index-id that is set up doesn't appear on the elk host. This is the config of the target logstash:
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
    codec => "json"
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["[event][original]"]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    hosts=> "${ELASTIC_HOSTS}"
    user=> "${ELASTIC_USER}"
    password=> "${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}"
    cacert=> "certs/ca/ca.crt"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}

Everything works fine if I move the index: ... entry from the filebeat.inputs section to output.logstash; but I want to eventually add more inputs on that host that should end up in another index.
What is going wrong?

@MuratK. something like this, although the question was really about the index being part of the input section specifically. I will check out the approach in the blog and see if it solves my problem, if so I'll let you know so you can post it as an answer. Thanks for the link either way.

When you set the index option on a filesteam input in filebeat the result depends on the output type. For an elasticsearch output it sets the index that is written to. For other output types it sets the raw_index field in the event metadata. If you have a filestream input configured as
- type: filestream
  id: my-filestream-id
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /tmp/foo*.txt
  index: "someRandomName"

Then the event the logstash output receives will have:
 "@metadata" => {
    "raw_index" => "someRandomName",
    ...

you can then use a sprintf reference (index => "%{[@metadata][raw_index]}") in the logstash output section.

Hmmm I tried with output { elasticsearch { index => "%{[metadata][raw_index]}" } } in the logstash conf, but that doesn't seem to work either :( But I think I'll have to stick with my workaround, leaving the company in two days anyway :P
